# Why is the autocorrelation between a signal and uncorrelated zero-mean stationary white noise not zero?

Tags: autocorrelation

I have a signal `x[n]` that is generated by some uncorrelated white noise:

$ x[n] = b_1x[n-1] + b_2x[n-2] + v[n]$

To find the autocorrelation sequence, I have done the following:

$ r_{xx}(k) = E[(b_1x[n-1] + b_2x[n-2] + v[n])x(n-k)]$

$ = b_1r_{xx}(1+k) + b_2r_{xx}(2+k)$

Which is correct (the signal `x[n]` is stationary) except that I am missing the noise variance.

The answer given by my lecturer is:

[image: answer]

Can anyone explain the intuition behind this result?

It was to my understanding that if `v[n]` is uncorrelated with `x[n]` then:

$ E[v[n]x[n-k]] = 0 \text{ }\forall\text{ }k $

I am aware that $ R_{vv}(k) = \sigma^2\delta(k) $ which is where I believe this comes from, however, there is no $E[v[n]v[n-k]]$ in the derivation?

Below is the question copied from the exam paper.
[image: question]

Comment: I guess that is my confusion. The question I am reading states that v[n] is uncorrelated with x[n], which contradicts the definition of x[n]. You say v[n] is uncorrelated for n>m but the answer suggests its for all n /= 0?

Comment: @CagdasOzgenc I have attached a picture of the question from the paper, if that helps.